# AngularJS input to accept integers and special characters

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex, html

```
<input type="text" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]*$/" id="players" name="players" ng-model="team.players"/>
```

I'd like the above input to accept integer numbers along with the following special characters.
`. + -`

How can I filter this with minimum code?

I tried some examples found on Internet, with none of them are working correctly whatsoever.

**Note:** My goal is to accept integer values (along with the special characters mentioned above) but not decimals.

Comment: try this ng-pattern="/^\d+$/" type="number"

Comment: still able to type `.` I just want to block numeric character. but somehow regex is not filtering alphanumeric.

Comment: you will be able to type those characters but your model will be invalid

Comment: That is correct. I was wondering if `<input type="number"` blocks alphabet, then there is a way to block alphanumeric. I think atm I will just write js code to block keyCode.

Comment: I'm not able to test but maybe this pattern (or something like this) would be better: `^[^.][0-9]*$`

Comment: http://regexr.com/  problem in regular expression useful to build regex expression

Comment: [0-9\.\+\-] try this solution which will allow integers as well as only (.,+,-) special characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us assume that want to accept the following numbers, which are all integral: `37`, `-10`, `-09`, `+23`, `7.`, `7.000`.

The following regex:

```
^[+\-]?[0-9]+(\.0*)?$
```

will accept an optional leading sign, one or many digits, and an optional decimal point with only trailing zeroes. It will deliberately not accept numbers without any digits before the decimal point, e.g. `.00`. The regex is anchored with `^` and `$` to ensure that the whole string matches.

Depending on the regex dialect you may have to quote more or less characters.

Answer (score 0):

I try regex, but it didn't work. 
I end up with this code below,

```
$scope.reg.players=parseInt($scope.reg.players)
```

So when user put `1.2` it will convert to `1`. 
If user type `1.` then it print invalid input error.